# Correct formatting JSON with PHP for HighCharts

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

**Hi everyone!** I am using HighCharts to create a column chart that drillsdown into a stacked column bar. The example that I found is working, now I only have to get my data in the correct format. I'm not getting the `{` and `[`'s correct..

The example which I am working with is: http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/21/

I am creating JSON files in my Laravel 5.2 application and loading them into the JavaScript. I create these JSON files in a controller which gets data from a mongo driver. I will add a partial code:

```
$drilldown_data = array();
$data_drilldown_file = array();

foreach ($id_array as $char) {        
    $cursor = $collection->find(array("_id" => new MongoId($char)));
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        if (is_array($document['comments'])) {
            foreach ($document['comments'] as $comments) {
                $data_filtered = array();
                array_push($data_filtered, array('filtered on language', $comments['nr_filtered_on_language']));
                array_push($data_filtered, array('filtered on non relevant', $comments['nr_filtered_on_relevant']));
                array_push($data_filtered, array('filtered on spam', $comments['nr_filtered_on_spam']));
                array_push($data_filtered, array('filtered on etc', $comments['nr_filtered_on_etc']));


                $array_4 = array("name" => $document['project_id'],
                        "data" => $data_filtered
                    );
                array_push($drilldown_data, $array_4);
            }
        }
    }
}

array_push($data_drilldown_file, json_encode($drilldown_data));
$results = File::put('/path/to/json.json', $data_drilldown_file);
// Exception caught!
if ($results === false) {
    die("Error writing to file");
}
// Replace the "][" with ",", needed for multiple selected projects!
$oldMessage = "][";
$deletedFormat = ",";
$str = file_get_contents('/path/to/json.json');
$str = str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat", $str);
$str = substr($str, 1, -1);
// Replaces the old content with the new!
file_put_contents('/path/to/json.json', $str);
```

This produces the following JSON format:

```
{
    "name": 1,
    "data": [
        ["filtered on language", 223],
        ["filtered on non relevant", 1985],
        ["filtered on spam", 2356],
        ["filtered on etc", 2035]
    ]
}, {
    "name": 1,
    "data": [
        ["filtered on language", 223],
        ["filtered on non relevant", 1985],
        ["filtered on spam", 2356],
        ["filtered on etc", 2035]
    ]
}, {
    "name": 1,
    "data": [
        ["filtered on language", 223],
        ["filtered on non relevant", 1985],
        ["filtered on spam", 2356],
        ["filtered on etc", 2035]
    ]
}, {
    "name": 67,
    "data": [
        ["filtered on language", 223],
        ["filtered on non relevant", 1985],
        ["filtered on spam", 2356],
        ["filtered on etc", 2035]
    ]
}, {
    "name": 67,
    "data": [
        ["filtered on language", 223],
        ["filtered on non relevant", 1985],
        ["filtered on spam", 2356],
        ["filtered on etc", 2035]
    ]
}, {
    "name": 67,
    "data": [
        ["filtered on language", 223],
        ["filtered on non relevant", 1985],
        ["filtered on spam", 2356],
        ["filtered on etc", 2035]
    ]
}
```

But the format has to be like:

```
{
                                'Animals': {
                                    name: 'Animals',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Cows', 2],
                                        ['Sheep', 3]
                                    ]
                                },
                                    'Animals2': {
                                    name: 'Animals',
                                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                                    data: [
                                        ['Cows', 22],
                                        ['Sheep', 13]
                                    ]
                                },
                                    'Fruits': {
                                    name: 'Fruits',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Apples', 5],
                                        ['Oranges', 7],
                                        ['Bananas', 2]
                                    ]
                                },
                                    'Fruits2': {
                                    name: 'Fruits',
                                    color: 'red',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Apples', 15],
                                        ['Oranges', 17],
                                        ['Bananas', 22]
                                    ]
                                },
                                    'Cars': {
                                    name: 'Cars',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Toyota', 1],
                                        ['Volkswagen', 2],
                                        ['Opel', 5]
                                    ]
                                },
                                    'Cars2': {
                                    name: 'Cars',
                                    color: '#bada55',
                                    data: [
                                        ['Toyota', 11],
                                        ['Volkswagen', 21],
                                        ['Opel', 15]
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
```

Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Save yourself the work and use `json_encode()` on your array. You should never attempt to encode JSON on your own.

Comment: you have to change php code to convert animal id to name

Comment: I am using `json_encode($drilldown_data)` at the end of my code

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand which part you are having trouble with. How to properly construct the php array to get the desired format? The necessary php format to result in the JSON you posted can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/27/ if that's of any help